# Combining trailer tail lamp and turn signal onto one wire

Tags: wiring, light

I am looking to attach a light to my tow vehicle that will be powered when towing via a 12V wire.

I also will have a 2nd wire that will supply 12V when the turn signal is turned on. At this point, I am not sure this is even possible but what I am looking for is when 12V is supplied to the turn signal, the light will flash in sync with the turn signal. Of course this is now backwards, because 12V would mean ON and 0V would mean OFF. So there needs to be some delay or some way of detecting when the turn signal has received 0V and not received 12V within a certain time period, that it would default back to the light being on.

Comment: Hmm... no delays needed. Here's some hints: 1) Look for how to implement an Exclusive-OR logic function. 2) You can implement any logic function using simple relays. :) Let's see if you can find the answer. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: I understand computers, so that makes sense, just need to find out how to do this with electronics.

Comment: You can do it with 2 relays per light. Probably the most robust solution. Diodes and transistors are finicky. Don't they already sell these things for trailers? The combine brake lights and turn signals so you can use one light per side on a trailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am looking to attach a light to my tow vehicle that will be powered when towing via a 12 V wire.

I wouldn't tow via a 12 V wire. But I assume you just got your word order mixed up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV6Lnl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Car circuit.*

In a car the light switch provides a path to ground when in the off position.

- When lights are switched on current flows through the lamp from left to right.
- If the turn signal is switched on it puts 12 V on both sides of the lamp so it turns off. It will blink in anti-phase with the lights on the car. (This may be a problem for the guy behind.)
- If lights are off and the turn signal given the lamp will blink in unison with the vehicle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU2vF5.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. An additional relay is required to have the same effect on a single wire feeding the trailer.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how the bulb is currently powered. One way would be to use a relay to cut out the power to the bulb if the 12v signal is detected.

You could also use a switch to do that for a DC circuit. ....

The possibilities are endless.